# SharePoint calculated column with hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, json-formatting

I have a SharePoint list as "Training Courses" and inside this, I have added a calculated column named "Website URL".

Here, My requirement is if a user enters the website name in the title column, then we will get Website URL under the calculated column.

[image]

Please, suggest any formula for implementation...

Comment: All the websites will have same URL format? For example: `https://www.spguides.com` and `https://www.enjoysharepoint.com`.

Comment: Yes, same URL format

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint online calculated columns does not support HTML anymore to create a clickable hyperlink.

So, I will suggest you to use the JSON formatting to make it clickable.

**Solution 1**:

1. Create a Website URL calculated column with this formula: `="https://www." & [Title] & ".com"`
2. Apply JSON column formatting for your calculated column using this JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "@currentField"
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Solution 2**:

1. Create a Website URL calculated column with simple formula like: `="Website URL"`
2. Apply JSON column formatting for your calculated column using this JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "[$Title]",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='https://www.' + [$Title] + '.com'"
  }
}
```

Where `Title` is the name of your internal column storing website name. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

Apply JSON column formatting by following steps given here: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#get-started-with-column-formatting)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: JSON format is not working (In 1st solution) sir

Comment: Solution 2 working for you? For solution 1, you have to apply JSON formatting to your calculated column and not Title column. Also, what do you mean by not working, is it not showing link or link is non-clickable?

Comment: Here, Link is Not showing and I applied JSON format to the calculated column only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147472/discussion-between-ganesh-m-and-ganesh-sanap).

Comment: After creating calculated column, is it showing the link correctly (in text format, non-clickable)?

Comment: After creating the Calculated column, it shows the non-clickable link. Then, once added the JSON format it is not showing. But In the same case, 2nd solution is working

Comment: I have tried both the solutions before posting the answer and both are working fine for me. Anyway, glad solution 2 worked for you!

Comment: Hi @GaneshM, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept my response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.